# Difference between prune and recursive-exclude in setuptools?

Tags: python-2.7, manifest, setuptools, setup.py, egg

I am using `setuptools` to package a custom module for deployment, which should not include certain files in the `data/` directory that were used for development. I have succesfully excluded the necessary files using `recursive-exclude data/ *` in my `MANIFEST.in` file, but I also see that I could do this via `prune data/`

Both approaches remove the intended files from `package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` after packaging via `python setup.py egg_info`

Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 16):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#commands) behaviour is:

- `recursive-exclude dir pat1 pat2` takes the directory `dir` and ignores all the files that match patterns `pat1` and `pat2`
- `prune dir` will exclude all files within the directory `dir`

So in your case `recursive-exclude dir *` and `prune dir` should have the same behaviour, except that `prune` will remove the whole directory, whereas `recursive-exclude` will preserve an empty folder.

Comment: Ah! I was looking at the setuptools docs rather than distutils... Anyway, `recursive-exclude` seems to get rid of empty folders as well. Looking at the docs, I think the only difference is that `recursive-exclude` allows you to specify file types whereas `prune` removes the entire directory.